# JavaScript for loop only looping once

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I have a for loop in JavaScript, which is looping through to set the values in a CSS Menu Accordion. It's setting the first one correctly, but it's not continuing through the loop, and I can't seem to figure out why or where it's stopping. It's getting to the end of the first loop as I've checked with outputting to the console. I know I shouldn't really be setting the ID as a number, but for the moment it's the best idea I have as to how to set the ID incrementing without loads of code. The JavaScript function is:

```
function displayInfo()
{
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("blogPost");

    var count = 1;
    document.getElementById("start").id = count;

    total = x.length;

    for(i=0; i<total;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(count).id = count;

        title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("postTitle")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue);
        document.getElementById("title").href=title;
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=title;

        text=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("postText")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue);
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=text;


        quote=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("postQuote")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue);
        document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML=quote;

        link=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("postLink")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue);
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML=link;

        date=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("postDate")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue);
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML=date;

        tags=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("postTags")[i].childNodes[i].nodeValue);
        document.getElementById("tags").innerHTML=tags;

        count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

This runs on

```
<body onload="displayInfo()">
```

and then the values are set in

```
<article class="accordion">

        <section id="start">

            <h2><a href="/" id ="title"></a></h2>
            <p id="text"></p>
            <p id="quote"></p>
            <p id="link"></p>

            <b id="foot"><p id="date"></p></b>
            <b id= "foot"><p id="tags"></p></b>

        <section>
        </article>
```

I'm not sure if it's because it's being called on page load, but wherever else I put it it doesn't work as expected and this is the closest I've got.
Thanks for any help on where I've gone wrong!

Comment: `document.getElementById(count).id = count;`. There are 2 possible outcomes : an error because the element isn't found. Or no change at all. It's very hard to figure what you imagined would happen.

Comment: For a start, you can't set element id as number (`document.getElementById("start").id = count;`).

Comment: @haim770 You can, it's just converted to a string (as is common in JS)

Comment: What is the point of this `document.getElementById(count).id = count;` ? Please explain to me cause I'm missing the logic here.

Comment: @dystroy, At least for HTML 4 spec, you can't (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id).

Comment: Was basically trying to set the id of the section to 1, and then after the first loop, 2, etc. I have a feeling I just need to start from scratch with this and try something different.

Comment: So it should be `(count - 1).id = count`, right? Because there is no use to get an element by id and change it to the same id.

Comment: `document.getElementById()` take a string as an argument. Try to change `document.getElementById(count)` to `document.getElementById(count.toString())` Or create new variable `var countString = count.toString()`

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown There's count = count + 1; at the end increasing it to a different value

Comment: I know, but is the same as changing `getElementById("a").id = "a"`, right ? It is the same variable, that is what I mean. So if you want to change the previous element id, which should be `1` to `2`, you have to use the previous id, which is `currentCount - 1`.

Comment: var count = 1; document.getElementById("start").id = count; sets it initially, then initialised as the first value, then incremented after the first loop? I think I might be missing your point?